# Javascript - Mostrar div cuando resultado = 0

Tags: javascript

Tengo algunos problemas con mi script.

Tengo un script que funciona muy bien, que me muestra algunos divs ocultos cuando el valor de `#total` está entre **99.99** y **299.99**, pero ahora estoy intentando **mantener oculto el div** `#alert` **cuando el resultado de** `#total` **es igual 0** (cero), y aunque intenté algunas funciones extras (comentadas en el script), la verdad es que no conseguí resultados.

No me funciona el invento...

Ver **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5fdum6wk/)** online ( JSFiddle )

Qué estoy haciendo mal aquí...?

Gracias.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function manageRegalo() {

var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());

if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
total = totalStorage;
}

if(total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {
console.log("PASS");
$('#regalo').show();

//if(total === 0) {
//if(total == 0) {
//if(total < 1) {
//$('#alert').hide();
//}

//else{
//$('#alert').show();
//};

if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
$('.tooltip').show();
window.setTimeout(function() {
$('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
}, 9000);

//--------------------

if (!$("#notify")[0].paused) { //play audio
$("#notify")[0].pause(); //play audio
$("#notify")[0].currentTime = 0; //play audio

} else {  // play audio
setTimeout(function() { //play audio
$("#notify")[0].play(); //play audio
})}; //play audio

//--------------------

localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
}

} else {
console.log("FAIL");
$('#regalo').hide();
}
}

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
const target = event.target;
if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
manageRegalo();

localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val()));
}
});
manageRegalo();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#alert , .tooltip {
display: none
}

@media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape) {
#alert {
display: block !important
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regalo">Regalo</div>
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
<div id="alert">Alert</div>
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que el problema lo tienes en:  `if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) { total = totalStorage; }` ya que no permites que `total` valga cero.

Comment: @phpMyGuel ... Me comentaron quitar mi fragmento fuera del `if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99){ .. }` pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Ubique donde lo ubique, no me funciona...

Comment: Actualiza tu demo, describes lo que quieres hacer con `#alert` pero aparentemente lo estas haciendo targeteando `.tooltip`

Comment: @Cristian Carrillo ... `.tooltip` no tiene problemas. Se muestra junto a `#regalo`. Esto funciona bien. Mi problema es el div `#alert`

Answer (score 0):

**0** es un valor que no es mayor que **99.99** y además menor **299.99**, entonces nunca puedes evaluarlo dentro de `if(total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {` la solución en mi opinón sería algo como:

```
if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {
  //código aqui
} else if (!total) {
  // código aqui
  $('#alert').show();
}
```

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Qué significa `//cosas aqui` ...?. Gracias

Comment: @Pablo_Web Lo cambié por `//código aquí`. Me refiero a que en realidad no importa que esté ahí adentro, lo importante es lo que esté adentro o afuera del if. Lo puse así para que quede bien bien claro.

Comment: Es que no logro comprender cómo (con tu ejemplo), puedo detectar que `#total` = 0

Comment: @Pablo_Web, ! es un operador lógico llamado NOT, que niega lo que tiene enfrente, de modo que !total se lee NOT total.
Te dejo una página de la documentación de php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

!total Sería true (y por tanto, se ejecutaría lo que está dentro de ese if) si total tiene valor de 0 o NULL

Comment: No me funciona. Algo estoy haciendo mal, y no encuentro qué. Edité mi post con **una demo online** ... [enlace] ( https://jsfiddle.net/1hztsem5/ )

Comment: @Pablo_Web entiendo que sería algo asi https://jsfiddle.net/h5rd7xz1/1/

Comment: @Emeeus Parece que funciona muy bien, gracias pero **no me respeta** que el `#alert` sólo debe hacerse visible como indica el media `@media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape){#alert{display: block !important}}` ... ¿Hay solución de indicarlo en el script...?